# issue cursor.description never returns square bracket in column name (python 2.7 + sqlite3) alias

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm trying to use cursor.description to get sqlite3 column names, and nothing I try works when the column name contains a square bracket. In looking at https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html, it seems I might be able to use the detect_types param of sqlite3.connect(), but that does not seem to have any effect. Here's what I have tried:

```
import sqlite3
import sys

# tried using detect_types=0, sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES, or sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
# all 3 values yield the same result
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:', detect_types=0)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('select 1 as "H[ello"')

for x in cur.description:
    sys.stderr.write("should write H[ello, but only writes: " + x[0])
    # output:
    #   should write H[ello, but only writes: H
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[` appears to be a *special case* - it is [filtered by the `sqlite3` module while building a column name for the cursor description](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c30098c8c6014f3340a369a31df9c74bdbacc269/Modules/_sqlite/cursor.c#L202):

```
PyObject* _pysqlite_build_column_name(const char* colname)
{
    const char* pos;

    if (!colname) {
        Py_RETURN_NONE;
    }

    for (pos = colname;; pos++) {
        if (*pos == 0 || *pos == '[') {
            if ((*pos == '[') && (pos > colname) && (*(pos-1) == ' ')) {
                pos--;
            }
            return PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize(colname, pos - colname);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm though not sure why - probably related to compatibility with MS Access.

Comment: Thanks. Should the behavior be impacted by the detect_types setting? If so, seems like it should be easy to modify _pysqlite_build_column_name (will need an additional arg to indicate detect_types) and then modify how it's called (from _pysqlite_query_execute at least, maybe elsewhere as well). What's the best forum to raise this issue in and pursue a patch (which we'd be happy to provide if we have clarification on how it's supposed to work)?

Comment: @mwag yeah, I would expect `detect_types` to have effect on the behavior. I would definitely raise an issue at the [Python issue tracker](https://bugs.python.org/). Thanks, good question!